# ¿Existe alguna manera de exportar un dataframe a un archivo pdf?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Tkinter, mi output resulta siendo un dataframe. Me gustaría que el usuario pudiera exportar esa información como archivo pdf ¿Conocen alguna solución?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a pasar el data frame de Pandas a HTML y luego haciendo la conversión a PDF.

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit as pdf

df = <data frame>
df.to_html(archivo_html)
pdf.from_file(archivo_html, archivo_pdf)
```